# Physical implementation of error detection scheme with an ancilla qubit

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, error-correction, stabilizer-code, quantum-control

I have two data qubits coupled with an ancilla qubit. I need a Hamiltonian H such that:

If the ancilla qubit is in state $|0⟩$, do nothing on the 2 qubits.
If the ancilla qubit is in state $|1⟩$, apply an operation $Z1 \otimes Z2$, where $Z1$ and $Z2$ are the Z gates on qubit $1$ and $2$, respectively.
Our Hamiltonian should look like:

$H = |0⟩⟨0|  \otimes  I + |1⟩⟨1|  \otimes   (Z1  \otimes  Z2)$

Here $I$ is just the identity operation on the two data qubit subspace. How do I physically implement this $H$? What kind of pulses (single qubit rotations), couplings etc would I apply to these three qubits? Is there any literature where it has been done experimentally?